# Fast way to calculate min distance between two numpy arrays of 3D points

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, distance

I would like to know if there is a fast way to calculate Euclidian distance between all points of a 3D numpy array (`A [N,3]`) to all points of a second 3D numpy array (`B [M,3]`).

I should then get an array `C` which would be `[N, M]` with all distances from points of array `A` to points of array `B` to then use `np.min()` along specified axis to get all minimum distances from points of set `A` to points of set `B`.

This is the way I have done the implementation so far :

```
distances = np.repeat(9999, len(A))
for i, point in enumerate(A):
  min_distance = np.min(np.sqrt(np.sum(np.square(point - B), axis=1)))
  distances[i] = min_distance
```

Is there any way to get rid of the for loop...?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix; dist_mat = distance_matrix(A,B)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

# arrays with xyz coordinates of all points 
a = np.asarray([[xa1,ya1,za1],...,[xan,yan,zan]])
b = np.asarray([[xb1,yb1,zb1],...,[xbn,ybn,zbn]])

# reshaping to be able to calculate the distance matrix
a_reshaped = a.reshape(a.shape[0], 1, 3)
b_reshaped = b.reshape(1, b.shape[0], 3)

"""calculation of all distances between all points  - creates a 
len(a) x len(b) matrix""" 
distance = np.sqrt(np.sum((a_reshaped - b_reshaped)**2, axis=2))
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

If the scipy method doesn't work or if you do have other reasons, here is a numpy way-

```py
import numpy as np


x = np.random.random((200, 3))
y = np.random.random((100,3))

x = x.reshape((-1, 1, 3))                 # [200x1x3]
y = np.expand_dims(y, axis=0)             # [1x100x3]
y = y.repeat(x.shape[0], axis=0)          # [200x100x3]

distance = np.linalg.norm(y-x, axis=2)    # Difference is [200x100x3] and norm results in [200x100]
```