# how to match one axis with multiple numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, merge, match

Background:
I have an rgb image with three diminution (W, H, C), where C = 3. I want to mask a few colors like (0,0,255) , (0,255,255) in this image. The problem becomes matching the last axis of the image with a list of colors I defined. `color_list = [[255,0,0], [255,255,0], [255,0,255]] # just an example`

It is easy to do it with one color,

```
mask = np.all(image == [255,0,0], axis = 2)
```

But I have to run a for loop if I have multiple colors.

```
masks = [np.all(image == color, axis = 2) for color in color_list]
mask = np.any(masks, axis=0)
```

Question:
Any elegant way to get the mask with multiple colors?

Comment: I think your method is plenty elegant.

Comment: @orlp can you check the solution I write below and verify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have one way using broadcasting which is more efficient since it will loop in C. Basically make arrays comparable. It might look difficult at beginning, but once you know how it works this is all you will use [conditions apply]....

```py
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[[255,   0,   0],[  0, 255,   0], [  0, 255,   0], [  0, 255,   0]], [[255,   0,   0],[  0, 255,   0], [  0, 255,   0], [  0, 255,   0]]])
print(x.shape)
# (2, 4, 3)

color_list = np.array([[255,0,0], [255,255,0], [255,0,255]])
print(color_list.shape)
# (3, 3)

# make array compatible
x = x[:, :, np.newaxis, :]

### Analogy for interpreting broadcasting
# Here repeating is for analogy and does not mean it will allocate new copy of memory
# element wise comparision, possibler due to broadcast
# shape of x is (2, 4, 1, 3)
# By broadcasting conceptually x will be repeated along axis=2 this will make (2, 4, 3, 3)
# color_list will be repeated over (2, 4) making it (2, 4, 3, 3) and they will have same shape also the final shape after == will be (2, 4, 3, 3)
f1 = np.all(x[:, :, np.newaxis, :] == color_list, axis=3)
#array([[[ True, False, False],
#        [False, False, False],
#        [False, False, False],
#        [False, False, False]],
#
#       [[ True, False, False],
#        [False, False, False],
#        [False, False, False],
#        [False, False, False]]])

mask = np.any(f1, axis=2)
```

We have target array with shape `(W, H, C) == (2, 4, 3)` and we need to find size 3 arrays of `color_list == [[255,0,0], [255,255,0], [255,0,255]]`

Ideally we would like to do `cross comparison`, by that I mean if one side have `M` and other side `N` entries, then after some operations we would like `M * N` results. This would seem like repeating M entries each N times and comparing. While that may seem not possible at first glance, but numpy provides **broadcasting**. This will **conceptually** repeat the entries like your for loop(actually it highly memory efficient, it wont create actual copies)

So we need to broadcast, to make these two arrays compatible, but they are not compatible, as mentioned in [broadcasting rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html#general-broadcasting-rules) shapes are compared right to left and they need to be same or one of them must be 1.

color_list shape is (3, 3), x shape is (2, 4, 3). We will add new axis in x to make it compatible for broadcasting, which is `x[:, :, np.newaxis, :]` which has shape (2, 4, 1, 3). Now both are compatible and we can compare.

Compare along last axis which is color channel axis=3 and then on last but one axis which his axis = 2 will give (W, H) boolean where each entry represents True if the color channel triple was there in `color_list`.

This technique is exactly the same which can be used to calculate the distance matrix when two arrays of points are givenlike here [Fast way to calculate min distance between two numpy arrays of 3D points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64343663/fast-way-to-calculate-min-distance-between-two-numpy-arrays-of-3d-points)